# Sublime Text 2 + Perl

Tags: perl, sublime-text

У меня на флешке находится установленный Sublime Text 2 и сборка Перла Citrus. Как мне заставить Sublime Text 2 запускать Perl скрипты одним нажатием в самом редакторе?

Answer (score 2):

В редакторе Sublime text 2 выбираем пункт `Tools->Build System->New build system`

Записываем

```
{"cmd": ["путь к интерпретатору perl", $file]  }
```

Сохраняем

Далее выбираем нашу `buil system`

```
 ctrl-b
```

Profit! ;)